# GPG key import through PHP not working (works in shell)

Tags: php, shell, exec, gnupg

I have to import a GPG key in a PHP script, it works using the command line

```
gpg --import "/home/me/pubkey.txt"
```

but does not work using the PHP `gpg` class with the `import` method even with the `gnupg_import` function.

My configuration is:

- RedHat Enterprise Linux 5
- PHP 5.1.6
- GnuPG 1.4.5
- GPGme 1.1.8
- GPG extension 1.3.1

I also tried using the `exec` or `system` functions of PHP, but with no success, with the same command line (`exec('cat "/home/me/pubkey.txt"')` works so the file is readable).

**Edit**: 
It works on Ubuntu 9.10 Server with GnuPG 1.4.9, PHP 5.2.6.

Comment: The problem is that there is no error message given by gnupg_geterror(). No PHP warning, nothing.

Comment: Have you tried exec and system with the optional reference parameters, and print_r their value? Is the gpg executable in safe_mode_exec_dir? E.g. on my Ubuntu cat is in /bin/, while gpg is in /usr/bin/, see notes at http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: An empty array for the $output and "2" for the $return_var, so "Unexpected error". Safe mode is Off on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it !
I am the one who had the problem, Fabien posted this question on SO.

It's a file permission issue : it tried to write in the .gnupg file on /root (the HOME env var) but PHP can't write in it.

We have to change the rights on this file so that PHP can write in it, or move this to a directory writeable by PHP.

What is the best solution ?